# How can I run my iPhone application when I decline an incoming call?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

How can I run my application when the user declines the incoming call, using the iPhone SDK?

Comment: You *might* be able to do this with a jailbroken phone. You definitely can't do this otherwise.

Comment: But without jailbroken in this link they had developed an application can u please go thru dis and tell me how cud it possib?? http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/agile-reply/id416445913?mt=8

Comment: It does not seem that the app is auto running after declining. After running by the user, it detects the last declined number. Are you sure that this app run automatically after user declines a call?

Comment: Ok then is it possible to detect the last declined number automatically??

Comment: That is definitely possible, as the app is doing. Though I don't know how to do that. You can edit this question or ask a new question asking that if Google does not provide any solution.

Comment: I didnt find any solution .I am struggling alot for this.If u found anything regarding to this please share with me.It really helps me.

Answer (score 0):

OK, just did some digging around in the SDK.  The closest thing I found is the [CoreTelephony framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CoreTelephonyFrameworkReference/_index.html) (new in iOS 4.0).  It has the ability to specify a block callback so you can be notified about the call changes.  Something like:

```
CTCallCenter *callCenter = [[CTCallCenter alloc] init];
[callCenter setCallEventHandler:^(CTCall *call) {
  NSLog(@"state changed on call: %@", call);
}];
```

You can check the `callState` of that `CTCall` object to see whether it's disconnected or what.  I don't know how you'd figure out offhand that the call was *declined*, but you can at least know when calls happen/change state.  If your app is in the background, then when you're foregrounded again, you'll get a single coalesced callback for each call.  If your app is not running at all, then I have no idea what happens when the app starts.

This is where I'd start looking, anyway.

Comment: ur answer is bit tricky but can I get the number tat I declined along with the call state??

Comment: Anyway Thanks for ur prompt idea.